# Advice on cloning disk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, rsync, clone, dd

I'm going to buy a second disk for backup, the same size as my laptops. I want to mount it in a casing via usb and backup an entire hdd every soemtime. That's because I want the posibility to just switch drives in case of something goes wrong. I'm using Linux and obviously the right tool seems to be *dd*. The thing is that my laptop drive has a speed of around 50-70 MB/s and usb 2.0 is 57 MB/s. So to copy my 250GB disk should take me more than 1 hour if I'm lucky. I can't wait this much. I want some differential backup. I read one of JWZ [articles](http://www.jwz.org/doc/backups.html). In it he gives more details for using rsync on Mac. He writes that there is possibility of making rsync'ed disk bootable.

So my question is: how to make rsync'ed hdd bootable under Linux or are there other 'quick backup' tools for Linux that would allow me to just swap drives? Or should I just stick to *dd* :( ?

Comment: Obviously your first backup will still take some time, and I don't think you're using the full 250GB are you? That said, I would create a `dd` backup first, and then use `rsync` to update the differential data.

Comment: you sould put that as answer .. short and painless solution

Comment: Usb 2.0 has a theoretical bandwidth of 480 Mb/s, but real world speeds are going to be 25-30 MB/s. (Yes, I'm using both Mb and MB in this comment)

Comment: @randolph-potter I think that will work. I just need to learn more on rsync. I dont quite understand how it works. Post is as answer. I will accept it once I check it in reality.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your first backup will still take some time, and I don't think you're using the full 250GB are you? That said, I would create a `dd` backup first, and then use `rsync` to update the differential data.

Comment: One more thing. Given that I have installed few OSes on my drive and I will always use rsync from the same OS, will I be able to backup other partitions. I mean logically 'rsync -a --exclude '/mnt/backup-drive*' / /mnt/backup-drive' should synchronize partitions wherever I mounted them. Right?  Gosh it is so much simpler to copy raw bytes.

Comment: The rsync may start getting dodgy with file permissions across file systems, so obviously dd is preferred in that case, but I think a good test might help.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that need exact copy from one disk to the other is the boot process. The `mbr` point to somewhere quite fix, after that Grub know how to find a file on the disk.

My advise is to make a minimal `/boot` partition that you clone with `dd`. (100MB are enough if you clean your kernels copies 3-4 times a year). And the other partition(s) are `rsync`'ed.

After a first full-disk `dd`. Next times, I would

- `mount -o remount,ro /boot`
- `dd` the MBR and the `/boot` partition
- `mount -o remount,rw /boot`
- `rsync` the other partitions.

I would also check cylinders and heads count to be sure to have similar enough disks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a flexRAID or a RAID_1.

To my understanding FLEXraid will do an initial Full backup of the data then a Differential backup their after.

Comment: I prefer once a day or a week depending on how much content changed. RAID is designed with constant disk access in mind. It just doesn't fit my need.